# Союз "тем более что"

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, при расчленении союза **"тем более что" "тем более"** будет рассматриваться как наречие в главной части предложения?

Comment: Спасибо, Алена, за интересный вопрос и за ваше внимание к русскому языку. Ваши вопросы делают форум лучше. Поздравляю вас с наступающим праздником, желаю счастья и успехов!

Comment: Благодарю! И Вас поздравляю с наступающим праздником! Желаю благополучия и отличного настроения!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй ответ

Интересную вы для меня  нашли задачку, поэтому я расскажу о ней в отдельном ответе.

1. Конечно, **вид придаточного** надо было сразу назвать, но я понадеялась на справочник. Мы все любим списывать, и я не исключение. Когда вы указали на вариант с расчленением союза, то вид придаточного нужно было уже определять в обязательном порядке, Ну ничего, в учебнике «Синтаксис современного русского языка» найду – присоединительное, наверное.  Ищу в этой теме, но там такого союза нет. Опять неудача! Даже значение союза ЧТО не могу определить.
2. Вот тогда и **приходится думать.**

*И это **тем более** удивительно, **что**  по моему предмету… И это  особенно удивительно **потому, что**  по моему предмету…*

Так это расчлененный союз **причины?** Вот там мы и поищем.  И точно, вот он, нашелся: *Мы заедем к друзьям за лыжами, **тем более что** нам по дороге.*

**А вот и информация про него.** Различаются собственно-причинные и несобственно-причинные отношения. Ко второй группе относятся **несобственно-аргументирующие** отношения – другими словами, причинно-аргументирующие.  В этом случае в придаточной части может указываться не основная причина, а **дополнительный довод**  в пользу утверждения в главной части.

Вот и в словарной статье для слова « более» есть этот союз:
**БОЛЕЕ,** сравнит. ст.; нареч. . 2. (с прил. и нареч.). Употр. для образования **сложной сравнительной степени**. Тот берег б. пологий. Надо относиться к себе б. критически.  **ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ ЧТО**, в зн. союза. Выражает **присоединение с оттенком обоснования.**

3. Присоединительный союз точно расчленяться не будет, а вот причинно-аргументирующий  в некоторых случаях **может расчленяться** по аналогии с союзом ПОТОМУ ЧТО. (Кстати, этот союз состоит из местоименной части и изъяснительного союза ЧТО.)  Расчленение возможно не в каждом предложении, а только  там, где **местоименную часть можно отделить от союзной**:  И это тем более удивительно, что  по моему предмету…

Местоименная часть должна относиться  **к прилагательному или наречию** и стоять в препозиции к ним, сравнить: И это удивительно, **тем более что**  по моему предмету…

4. **И вывод.**  Придаточные получаются действительно **разные:** присоединительное с оттенком обоснования без расчленения союза и  придаточное с местоименно-союзной связью.

Сравнить: *Он бежал быстро, **так что** успел на поезд.* –  *Он бежал **так быстро, что** успел на поезд.* Здесь значение следствия и значение степени + следствия. А вот в нашем случае союз ЧТО – изъяснительный .

5. А теперь вернемся **к заданному вопросу:**  И это тем более удивительно, что  по моему предмету…

Здесь «более» используется для образования **сравнительной степени**  для краткого прилагательного – «более удивительно», а «тем» – это местоименная часть расчлененного составного союза «тем… что».

Вот такое решение – частично списанное и частично самостоятельное. Возможно, будут какие-то замечания от участников форума по оригинальной части?

**6. Дополнительный вопрос**

В логико-грамматической части "срезались *же* они благодаря какому-то непонятному недоразумению"  **ЖЕ будет являться сочинительным союзом**, равным по значению союзу А, или всё-таки усилительной частицей?

А это мы уж точно спишем, адрес известный: Сложносочиненные предложения с противительными союзами. – **Сопоставительные отношения.**

1. Собственно-сопоставительное значение: **союз А**. Однородное сочинение.
   Сопоставляются ситуации из одного класса, которые различаются по каким-то признакам. Еще недавно Интернет был мечтой, а сегодня это реальность (сопоставление по времени).
2. Сопоставительно–выделительное значение: **союз ЖЕ**. Неоднородное сочинение (по структуре ЖЕ входит  состав второго предложения). *Он любит обсуждать дела по телефону, я **же** предпочитаю личную встречу.*

**Союз-частица ЖЕ** стоит не между предложениями, а после первого слова, с которым связано несходство, **акцентирует** на нем внимание.  В этом различие с союзом А, который обозначает чисто сопоставительные отношения **без выделения.**

Comment: Благодарю за такой исчерпывающий ответ! Очень помогли! У меня ещё вопрос: слово "удивительно" разве в этом предложении не краткое имя прилагательное, ведь, чтобы оно было наречием, нужен глагол? И к тому же "удивительно" выступает в роли именной части СИС.

Comment: Да,  вы правы, это краткое прилагательное в роли иименной части, но тогда это сравнительная степень прилагательного в краткой форме.

Answer (score 3):

Этот союз не расчленяется.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_730

**ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ ЧТО, союз**

Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «тем более что», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. **Между частями союза запятая не ставится.**

Это известие всех школьников страшно взволновало, **тем более что** наша дорога в школу проходила мимо реки… Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Дурной товарищ. Мне, сударыня, доктора велели ноги в тепле держать, **тем более что** мне сейчас нужно идти настраивать рояль к генеральше Шевелицыной. А. Чехов, Сапоги. Очень длинное у нас детство, почти двадцать лет, и такая же будет длинная и нудная старость, **тем более что** живем мы теперь дольше наших ровесников мужчин. И. Ефремов, Лезвие бритвы.

Comment: У А. П. Чехова в произведении "Скучная история" наблюдается подобный случай: 
                                                                        
"Аргумент, который все лентяи приводят в свою пользу, всегда один и тот же: они прекрасно выдержали по всем предметам и срезались только на моем, и это ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ удивительно, ЧТО по моему предмету они занимались всегда очень усердно и знают его прекрасно; срезались же они благодаря какому-то непонятному недоразумению". Может быть, что-то не так поняла. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: Это придаточные разного вида, я чуть позже поробую назвать вид в каждом случае. Это примерно такая же ситуация, как с союзом так что. Если он нерасчлененный, то это следствие, а если расчлененный, то степень + следствие.

Comment: Заранее благодарю!

Comment: И ещё вопрос по этому предложению: в логико-грамматической части "срезались же они благодаря какому-то непонятному недоразумению" "же" будет являться сочинительным союзом, равным по значению союзу "а", или всё-таки усилительной частицей?